# Everytime I install something in Windows 7 my resolution changes to 640 x 480

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, installer, resolution

I think I screwed something with the Compatibility Administrator, because every time I install something new, program, game, or anything the screen resolution changes to 640 x 480, and it goes back to 1280 X 1024 once the installer finishes. This extremely annoying by the way. My OS is Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was only able to resolve this issue via re-installing Windows 7 entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Many setups use the Microsoft Installer (MSI) that is built in into windows. Do a search for **msiexec.exe** in your Windows folder, you will likely find a few copies in:

- C:\Windows\System32
- C:\Windows\SysWOW64
- C:\Windows\winsxs.

Right-click + Properties on each of them and make sure nothing is checked on the compatibility tab.

Comment: Is there a reason why it would be set like that in the first place? Just curious -b

Comment: @bubu when Windows detects problems, it can suggest solutions that will alter compatibility settings. I have never seen windows applying compatibility settings on itself (msiexec) though. So that was just a wild answer guess at what I would check first.

Comment: Found the 3 versions of the msiexec.exe, and there are no checked settings on the Compatibility Mode Tab...